# large-scale document co-occurrence analysis

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, processing-efficiency

I have about 1000 files. Each of which contains about 20,000 documents. I also have a list of about 1,000,000 words.

I want to calculate how many time each word occurs with any other words. So, there is a sparse matrix of size 1M X 1M.

To speed up computation, I'm working on each file separately by doing the following:

1- Each core in my machine is processing a single file and outputing a file of the following format

```
WordId1 WordId2 Frequency
```

2- After doing each file, I merge the 1000 file into a single file.

This is my current approach but It takes so long to do it and I assume there should be much efficient way of doing it so your comments are welcome.

Comment: What's your definition of co-occurence? (Both words appear in the same document? Both words appear next to each other in a document? ...?)

Comment: @meriton same document.

Comment: Do you count the number of times they appear in a document or is it just 1 or 0 for both occurring any number of times?

Comment: if you have single document, where W1 encounters 2 times, and W2 - 3 times, what will be the frequency table?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov W1 W2 1

Comment: Have you profiled the processing? Where are the bottlenecks?

Comment: this is not a transitive relation: let doc1 is "w1 w2", doc2 is "w2 w3", then frequency for `w1 w3` is `0`.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov thanks. I meant w1 w2 f= w2 w1 f

Comment: such relations are called symmetric

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can get reasonable performance by a careful treatment of details. The problematic part seens to be the memory. With enough memory, you could avoid the writing out and merging.

When processing a single document, you could convert it into a `BitSet` when each bit is set if the corresponding word is present.

Your relation is symmetric, so I hope you only store `(a, b, count)` with `a < b`.

You need something like `Multiset<Pair<String, String>>` for counting, but there are more memory conserving structures. Your words are numbered, so each one can be represented with an `int` and a pair can be represented with a `long`. So maybe something like [LongIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TLongIntHashMap.html) would do. You need concurrency, so you could either use atomics for the entries or partition the map into `N` parts (via some hashing with `N` beeing bigger than the number of cores) and synchronize. It should be easy enough to build something on top of `AtomicIntegerArray`.

You didn't say if there's any chance of your result to fit into memory, but if so it could result into a huge speedup.

#### The requested explanation

The strings are numbered from 0 to one million which fits in an `int`. Two such number together fit in an `long` which can be used as a key for the `TLongIntHashMap`. For each document you identify all relevant String pairs, get the corresponding `long`s and increment the value in the `TLongIntHashMap`.

Here, only the increment need to be done under lock. As this locking would hinder concurrency I proposed to use multiple maps, each with its own lock. The incrementing could be grouped, so that multiple operation can be done with a single lock.

A better solution may be to use one `TIntIntHashMap` per word. Imagine you put all words (represented as `int`s) found in an document into a Set. Then you can loop like this

```
for (int w1 : words) {
    getLock(w1).lock();
    TIntIntHashMap map = getMap(w1);
    for (int w2 : words) {
        if (isLess(w1, w2) map.increment(w2);
    }
    getLock(w1).unlock();
}
```

Here, `isLess` is an arbitrary antisymmetric irreflexive relation used to avoid storing both `(a, b)` and `(b, a)`. While simply `w1 < w2` would do, it'd lead to rather imbalanced values (`getMap(0)` would be probably big and `getMap(1000000)` would be empty). Using `((w1 - w2) ^ ((w1 + w2) << 31)) < 0` should do.

Comment: could you explain more how LongIntHashMap would do?

Comment: @DotNet: Explanation added. In the meantime I've got more ideas, especially one for the case the memory doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some statistics like this,  I split the job by two step

step1: multi-thread counting: compute the partition id of each pair and output the respecting partition-file directly ( partition_id = (md5 of pair)/partition_count, the partition process is the keypoint) ,  ( I have tried to  hash_map to stat the data(when the size the larger than thread_hold , output the map_data to file, which save a lot of disk space，and i put output file in different disk,which speed the process a lot)

step2: multi-thread merge： merge the count output by step1 use map(this process is done in memory,if you are short of memory, choose larger partition_count)

notes: it is an easy job by mapreduce, step1 is map phrase, and step2 is reduce phrase, the key process is partiotion process which corresponding to the partition part before reduce process in hadoop

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting fundamental laws of complexity here. You are trying to process massive numbers of documents for massive numbers of words and produce massive data sets from that.

It's always going to be slow.

Some things that may speed it up:

1. Forget the list of a million words. Instead just accept any word as you find it in the text, you can always filter them later. If you do need to filter against the list then make sure the list is in an appropriate form (for example a HashSet) which allows you to check quickly.
2. This sort of thing is more likely to be IO bound than CPU bound so try running it on fast SSD drives - or if the files are small enough set up a RAM disk and run it from that. Do some monitoring to identify just where the bottlenecks are.
3. The processing on each set of files is as you've already identified very parallel so you could look at spreading it out not just over multiple cores but multiple machines.

Something to try (the overhead of database may actually make it slower):
Rather than doing the merge at the end you could just compile the results for processing one document together in memory. Once you finish processing then do a single batch insert into a database. The database will then allow you to query the results dynamically, using sum() etc to find the totals for each word combination. This actually gives you a more flexible/useful result than just the flat file and avoids the separate merge step.